# vpasolve(...) and solve(...) debugging (symbolic solving for the real roots of a 4th order polynomial function.)

Tags: matlab, debugging, numerical-methods, symbolic-math

(as I understand it)

I am trying to use matlab to solve for the roots of a 4th order polynomial (T of the NASA polynomial for enthalpy, if you are familiar) at a array of different independent values on the right side of the equation.

I am doing thermodynamics project of (a simplified version of!): finding adiabatic flame temperature of a boiler for an array of different intake temperatures and considering variable specific heats.

for this particular iteration of code the error is:

```
"Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not
compatible with the size of the right side.

Error in sym/privsubsasgn (line 1307)
            L_tilde2 = builtin('subsasgn',L_tilde,struct('type','()','subs',{varargin}),R_tilde);

Error in indexing (line 1138)
            C = privsubsasgn(L,R,inds{:});

Error in MCHE362_FinalProject_Pr2D_William_Rhinehart (line 39)
    Tab(i) = vpa(T2);"
```

I am using Matlab r2022a student edition.

```
clear
clc
syms tab2

Ti = (298:25:873);


%low temperature coefficients 

A_CO2l = [2.35677352e+00  8.98459677e-03 -7.12356269e-06  2.45919022e-09 -1.43699548e-13 -4.83719697E+04  9.90105222e+00];
A_H2Ol = [4.19864056e+00 -2.03643410e-03  6.52040211e-06 -5.48797062e-09  1.77197817e-12 -3.02937267e+04 -8.49032208e-01];
A_N2l  = [0.02926640E+02  0.14879768E-02 -0.05684760E-05  0.10097038E-09 -0.06753351E-13 -0.09227977E+04  0.05980528E+02];

%high temperature coefficients

A_CO2h = [3.85746029e+00 4.41437026e-03 -2.21481404e-06  5.23490188e-10 -4.72084164e-14 -4.87591660e+04 2.27163806e+00];
A_H2Oh = [3.03399249e+00 2.17691804e-03 -1.64072518e-07 -9.70419870e-11  1.68200992e-14 -3.00042971e+04 4.96677010e+00];
A_N2h  = [0.02926640e+02 0.14879768e-02 -0.05684760e-05  0.10097038e-09 -0.06753351e-13 -0.09227977e+04 0.05980528e+02];

hfCO2 = -393520 ;
hfH2O = -241820 ;
hfN2 = 0 ; 
hfCH4 = -74850;

RCO2 = 0.1889; % W
RH2O = 0.4615; % X
RN2 = 0.2968;  % Y

for i = 1:length(Ti)

    EQ = (      1*(hfCO2+(RCO2*tab2*(A_CO2h(1) + A_CO2h(2)*tab2/2 +A_CO2h(3)*(tab2^2)/3 + A_CO2h(4)*(tab2^3)/4 + A_CO2h(5)*(tab2^4)/5 + A_CO2h(6)/tab2))-(RCO2*Ti(i)*(A_CO2l(1) + A_CO2l(2)*Ti(i)/2 +A_CO2l(3)*(Ti(i)^2)/3 + A_CO2l(4)*(Ti(i)^3)/4 + A_CO2l(5)*(Ti(i)^4)/5 + A_CO2l(6)/Ti(i))))...
          +     2*(hfH2O+(RH2O*tab2*(A_H2Oh(1) + A_H2Oh(2)*tab2/2 +A_H2Oh(3)*(tab2^2)/3 + A_H2Oh(4)*(tab2^3)/4 + A_H2Oh(5)*(tab2^4)/5 + A_H2Oh(6)/tab2)-(RH2O*Ti(i)*(A_H2Ol(1) + A_H2Ol(2)*Ti(i)/2 +A_H2Ol(3)*(Ti(i)^2)/3 + A_H2Ol(4)*(Ti(i)^3)/4 + A_H2Ol(5)*(Ti(i)^4)/5 + A_H2Ol(6)/Ti(i))))...
          +  7.52*(RN2*tab2*(A_N2h(1) + A_N2h(2)*tab2/2 +A_N2h(3)*(tab2^2)/3 + A_N2h(4)*(tab2^3)/4 + A_N2h(5)*(tab2^4)/5 + A_N2h(6)/tab2)-(RN2*Ti(i)*(A_N2l(1) + A_N2l(2)*Ti(i)/2 +A_N2l(3)*(Ti(i)^2)/3 + A_N2l(4)*(Ti(i)^3)/4 + A_N2l(5)*(Ti(i)^4)/5 + A_N2l(6)/Ti(i)))))...
          -  hfCH4 ...
          == 0   );

    T2 = solve(EQ,tab2);

    Tab(i) = vpa(T2);
    
    
end
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, which should also say where in the code the error happens. Your statement for `EQ = …` is ridiculously large, that will be really hard to fix if it has a problem. Even balancing brackets in that monster is hard. Why not break it up into smaller bits?

Comment: Chris, I am adding the full error message now. I currently have listed the wrong error message for this iteration of code anyways.  I will work on breaking EQ up arithmetically on paper and then re inputting it into something neater.

Comment: I guess `vpa(T2)` returns more than one value, but you can only fit one value into `Tab(i)`. Make `Tab` a cell array?

Comment: I don’t see a clear reason for you to be using symbolic/variable precision math for this. Is there a reason you’re not using [`roots`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) for this?

Comment: this is it, it needed to be ```T2(i,:) = solve(EQ,tab2)``` and ```vpasolve()``` runs it much faster than doing ```vpa() ``` afterwards

Comment: I used symbolic math because I am somewhat familiar with it. I have only been using MATLAB for 1 semester now. If you have tips on how to rewrite this using ```roots()``` and it will return faster and with less error I would be open to it. The program is running wonderfully now, but it appears there is something fundamentally wrong with my  ```EQ``` as the values its returning are increasing the correct rate, but are far too low. The ball is in my court now, as this is a understanding-thermodynamics problem now. Thank you all for the help!